# WCF sharing model with services

Tags: java, web-services

I have two WCF webservices that expose several Web Methods.
Some of the Web Methods in each of the webservices return the same model (I mean, same class, different object)

When I generate the client code (in Java) for both Services (two different WSDLs), the common objects get generated twice (one for each service).

for example.
WCF Service 1 expose:

```
ObjectTest DoSOmeWork();
```

WCF Service 2 expose:

```
ObjectTest DoSOmeHARDWork();
```

In java i will have two ObjectTest, one for each service.

Is there a way to share these objects ?
Sometimes the client needs to call both services and reuse some objects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can going the WSDL route - you can however have a common class library that you can share among your services and your clients.

You could also use something like Automapper.

Comment: My client is in java. The server is in c#.  You are telling that i need to create the proxy classes in the class by hand and share them with all clients?

Comment: @user2055213 no - i was referring to a pure .net implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select "Reuse types" when adding or configuring a service reference. You can then point to an assembly containing those types. Client and service will use that assembly.

If you mean you want to share the classes between various Java clients, then you should look at the options for the tool that generates the proxy for those clients.

Comment: Client is in Java. How can i do this ?

Comment: wsdltojava is not helping me =P

Comment: @user2055213 then please rewrite your question showing some (relevant) code from two clients that you wish them to share. I do not know that tool nor its options.

Comment: PRetty simple, i hava an object X in wsdl One and Two. I have a generated client that consumes WSDL one and two. the tool (wsdltojava) generate two classes for X (one for each wsdl).

Comment: So, when this tool generates its classes, does it do so in separate files? Can you move or copy these files to a directory that both client projects can read from? Again, I have no experience with this tool so I cannot tell. You should update your question to make clear this is all about the Java client side, not WCF.